# Podman/Buildah Install/Use cling-xeus

Tags: dockerfile, conda, podman, xeus-cling

I am trying to get xeus-cling to work on a OCI image, currently I am using buildah + podman. I run into two problems

1. I try to create an environment with mamba/conda, however it needs `conda/mamba init bash` too run then to restart the shell. But its hard to get it to restart while its building, I have tried building multistage images, `exit`, running `/bin/bash`. I noticed `conda` checks too see if certain files are configured in a certain way, including `/home/joyvan/.bashrc`, I `cat`'d out the modified `.bashrc` and `COPY`'d it too the image -- no dice. `activate` tells me I need to run `init`
2. I have tried installing it without the environment, I keep getting the error

```
Encountered problems while solving:
 - nothing provides system needed by clangdev-5.0.0-default_0
```

I don't know which package specifically `clangdev-5.0.0-default_0` is in (hence a bunch of commented out C++ relevant packages in the Dockerfile)

I have even got notebook to run a couple of times (cant remember what
I did) but did not see the option to create a C++ notebook. I am
wondering if this may be due to the fact that

I have put my Dockerfile in its current state below (I went a little crazy with `Ctrl+Z`)

Thank you for reading

- TFB :)

```
FROM docker.io/jupyter/scipy-notebook:latest

SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]

RUN mamba install -y xeus -c conda-forge
RUN mamba install -y jupyterlab -c conda-forge

# RUN conda install gcc7 -c conda-forge
# RUN mamba install -y -c conda-forge clangdev
# RUN mamba install -y -c conda-forge/label/llvm_rc clangdev
# RUN mamba install -y -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 clangdev
# RUN mamba install -y -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 clangdev
# RUN mamba install -y -c conda-forge/label/broken clangdev
# RUN mamba install -y -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 clangdev


RUN mamba install -y -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 
# RUN conda init bash
# RUN conda create -n cling
# RUN conda activate cling
RUN mamba install -y xeus-cling -c conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the same image, a minimal working example of Jupyter with `xeus-cling` kernel capabilities is:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM docker.io/jupyter/scipy-notebook:latest

RUN mamba install -yn base nb_conda_kernels \
    && mamba create -yn xeus-cling xeus-cling \
    && mamba clean -qafy
```

**Build and run**

```bash
docker build -t jupyter-xeus:latest .
docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter-xeus:latest
```

Then, from Jupyter I can create C++11, C++14, and C++17 kernels. Here is a C++14 one after running some trivial cells:

[image]

### Additional Notes

These images have Jupyter installed in the **base** environment. If you want alternative kernels installed in other environments to get automatically picked up, we add `nb_conda_kernels` to the **base**.

The `xeus-cling` is then installed to a separate Conda environment.

One should almost always chain Docker RUN commands, since this avoids unnecessarily generating intermediates.

If you want additional software available in an environment, say `boost` in the `xeus-cling`, then include that in the creation - **do not run multiple `conda install` commands!**. E.g.,

```
RUN mamba install -yn base nb_conda_kernels \
    && mamba create -yn xeus-cling xeus-cling boost \
    && mamba clean -qafy
```

The `mamba clean -qafy` helps minimize the size of the image.

Answer (score -1):

There is a proper answer above, but I just wanted to post that I also have a "hack". You may have noticed if you enter the juypter interface there is a New -> Terminal option. Installing `xues-cling` worked on this terminal, so I just used it to install `xues-cling`, it wound up working, it can probably (and preferably) be done with `mamba`, but some of my other hacks at the time worked with `conda`

```
FROM docker.io/jupyter/scipy-notebook:latest

RUN pip install jupyter-console
RUN conda create -y -n xeus-cling
RUN jupyter console source activate xeus-cling
RUN conda install -y -c conda-forge xeus-cling
```

Comment: This doesn’t do what you think. Every Docker RUN command is a new shell, so this is still installing into **base**